# Difference between Sequence of Functions and Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, notation, sequence-of-function

I already know what is a Multivariable Function, which looks like the following:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x+y}$$
And I just know that a Sequence of Function looks like
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{x+n}$$
That's confusing to me. Why not, instead, just put n inside of the parentheses $$f(x,n)=\frac{x}{x+n}$$ where $$n \in N^*$$
 I wonder what's the difference between those two and can that sub <sub>n</sub> be considered as a input variable of $f$ ? 

 Thank you StackExchange. <3

Comment: I think it is just for convenience. For example, a real sequence $a_n$ is a function from natural numbers to reals but it is rarely written as $a(n)$

Comment: $f(x,n)$ is a multivariable function defined on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$, while $f(x,y)$ is a multivariable function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.